# Xcodeでアイコンの設定をしたのですがなぜか黒い枠ができてしまいます。

Tags: ios, xcode

[image: 設定画面]

上記のように設定したのですがアプリ起動時には[image: シュミレータ]

このように表示されてしまいます。
上記がアイコンです。

変更後

Comment: アイコンデータは使用する言語(SwiftかObjCか)に関係ありませんので、タイトルとタグを修正させていただきました。表示を見るに「そんな画像を作ったからそうなってるのでないの?」と言う気がします。画面キャプチャーではなく、アイコンに使用している画像そのもの(iPhone App/60ptのどちらか)を質問中に添付していただけますか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。確認しているのですが画像の背景は白です。Icon-App-60x60@2x.png

Comment: 画像データを拝見しましたが、明らかにアイコン画像として不適切なものになっています。簡単に回答の形でまとめてみます。

Answer (score 3):

使用されている画像がアイコンとして不適切なものになっています。

白背景の画面に表示されるとわかりにくいですが、透明色を使用しているため背景を青にするとこんな感じになります。

[image: 背景を青に染めた画像]

---

以下AppleのHuman Interface Guidelineより抜粋

(日本語版が見つからなかったので、拙訳ですがお許しを。)

## [App Icon](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/)

> **Keep the background simple and avoid transparency.** Make sure your icon is opaque, and don’t clutter the background. Give it a simple
> background so it doesn’t overpower other app icons nearby. You don’t
> need to fill the entire icon with content.
>
> **背景は単純にしておき、透明色は避けること。** アイコンは確実に不透明にして、背景をごちゃごちゃにしないでください。背景を単純にすることで周囲の他のアイコンに余計な影響を与えないようにします。アイコンの隅から隅まで中身を詰め込む必要はありません。
>
> **Keep icon corners square.** The system applies a mask that rounds icon corners automatically.
>
> **アイコンの角は四角いままにしておきます。** iOSのシステムが自動的にアイコンの角が丸くなるようなマスク処理を行います。

一つ目の背景色透明についてですが、iOSはアイコンを表示する際に背景にどんなものを表示するのかなんてことは一切保証していません。透明の場所には周りに表示されている画像がそのまま表示されているかもしれませんし、今回のあなたの例のように真っ黒になっているだけかもしれません。と言うわけで、透明色を使用すると全く意図しない変な表示になってしまう可能性があるので、使用そのものが禁止されているのです。

ここまで露骨に黒枠が見えてしまうと、アイコンの不備(HIG違反)でApp Storeの審査も通らない可能性が高いだろうと思います。透明色を一切使わない、四角いアイコンを用意して差し替えてください。(もちろん実際に表示される場合に角丸処理が行われることは想定して中身を配置する必要がありますが。)

Comment: 画像を四角くして再度行ってみたのですがやはり後ろに黒い影ができてしまいます。

Comment: @冨樫義紀 さん、 単に角を四角くしただけで、周囲の透明余白部分が残っているのではないですか?120x120や180x180の画像サイズいっぱいまで(透明ではない)背景色で埋まっているかご確認ください。